# How to use weather-icons with React JS?

Tags: javascript, sass, reactjs

So I am trying to use [weather-icons](https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons) in a React application.

I downloaded the [package](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/) and added it to my solution ([here](https://github.com/zunperior/wear4cast/tree/master/src/weather-icons)).

(I use [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) starter kit)

In a [Forecast.js](https://github.com/zunperior/wear4cast/blob/master/src/containers/Forecast/Forecast.js) container I added the following:

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchForecast} from 'redux/modules/weatherForecast';

@connect(
    state => ({forecast: state.weatherForecast.forecast}),
    {fetchForecast}
)
export default class Forecast extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          <i className="wi wi-day-sunny"></i>
        </div>);
  }

}
```

It doesn't work yet...

1. How do I reference weather-icons so these classes are recognized in my container?
2. Do I need css and less folders? (I would prefer to use scss since starter kit is using this)

My code structure:

```
[src]
 |--[containers]
 |       |--[Forecast]
 |              |--Forecast.js
 |
 |--[weather-icons]
        |--[css]
        |--[font]
        |--[less]
        |--[sass]
        |--[values]
```

**[My source code](https://github.com/zunperior/wear4cast)**

Comment: Questions asking to debug code need to contain an [MCVE] *within the question*.  Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS**.

Comment: @cimmanon - I have a link to the whole file above the code snippet and the snippet below is the only relevant part.
I don't think there any issues with css, I just don't know how to reference it in jsx.

Comment: Linking to code is not acceptable.  All code relevant to the problem needs to be **in the question**.

Comment: I see... ok I will fix my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is importing the css file directly; (As stated [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/weather-icons))

```
import 'weather-icons/css/weather-icons.css';
```

Note: Path can be changed. I've installed the weather-icons package through npm which means it is under node_modules.

And After importing the css file you can use it like below;

```
<i className="wi wi-day-lightning"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is doing this is Next js which does not allow to import global css, just use css modules!

`import is from "../../styles/weather-icons.min.module.css"`

And use it like this even with tailwind :D

`` <i className={`${is.wi} ${is["wi-day-cloudy"]} text-xl text-cyan-300`}></i> ``

[image]